# What is the acceleration necessary for a Brachistochrone transfer from Earth to Mars?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mars, earth, retrograde-orbit

With these orbital configurations,

[image]

[image]
source-[Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=earth%20to%20mars%20distance&go=Search&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=earth%20to%20mars%20distance&sc=8-22&sk=&cvid=1CA713A17CCB47C98BCB1889D094D857)

leaving Earth on Aug 16, 2106 and arriving on Mars October 10,2106, what is the lowest continuously-applied acceleration that can make what is sometimes loosely referred to as a 'Brachistochrone transfer starting at this date/orbital configuration and ending on this date

Comment: I've just added a bit more to my 2017 answer to [Brachistochrone variation for Earth-to-Mars Orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23088/12102). I think you're aiming for something a bit different here, could you edit your question to make the distinction clearer? If you feel your question is answered there, you could also vote your own question to be duplicate, but editing this to highlight the differences would be more fun!

Comment: I think the question comes down to, "what is the lowest continuously-applied acceleration that can make this transfer starting at this date/orbital configuration and ending on this date".

Comment: @ikrase I agree, I think the question should be edited and that made clear, and the use of "Brachistochrone transfer" be modified to "This is sometimes loosely referred to as a 'Brachistochrone transfer.'" I think this is a great orbital mechanics question!

Comment: @uhoh Should I edit it for the op then?

Comment: @ikrase Bob516 is quite an active and experienced user with 100+ posts so probably can decide for themselsves.

Comment: OK, never mind.